# iMessage App Extension quits in iPhone X simulator

Tags: xcode, ios11, imessage, imessage-extension, iphone-x

Its terminating even for apple demo code.
Refer the screen shot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does it crash on other simulators or just the iPhone X?

Comment: only on iPhone X

Answer (score 1):

I have found that after initially installing the app and receiving this error, you should go into the simulator messages app and manually enable your messages app as it will be disabled by default. Once you enable it, it should work.